# Not showing report I Created

Tags: reporting

I created a report name : Sample1 and it is save on public folder (Sandbox)

When Im going to deploy it to Prod (Change outbound sets )

Component Type : Report
Then Sample1 not showing

TIA !!

Answer (score 2):

As the user interface states:

> NOTE: Reports in "My Personal Custom Reports" and "Unfiled Public Reports" cannot be added to a change set and are not shown in this list.

You must first create a new custom report folder before you can add the report to the change set.

Also, [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=5), which may be slightly outdated, says:

> Reports stored in the My Personal Custom Reports folder (private reports) don’t appear in the list of reports that can be added to the change set. Reports stored in the Unfiled Public Reports folder appear in the list of reports that can be added to the change set, but they aren’t deployed even if added to the change set. To deploy a private or unfiled report using a change set, first copy or move the report to a different report folder.